# Can we read the google sheet of specific version?

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

Scenario: Multiple people are working on a single google sheet, hence it is getting updated constantly. I've a java program to read the google sheet data of the current version. 
However, I want to read the data of a particular time stamp or the named version.

For example: I want to get only the data of "Version 1.2". So that the further updates to this version doesn't affect my work.

[image: Screenshot of sheet's version history]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Revision methods in Drive API. First call the [Revisions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/list) to get a list of changes that happened. After obtaining the revisionId, use [Revisions.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/get) to obtain that revision.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi there !! I've already tried it, however, it is not meeting my requirements as it returns the list of revisions in the timestamp. My requirement says I want to get the "named" requirements.